# AccessToken from Azure ADB2C in MVC5 application

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, access-token, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

We are working on a MVC5 web application, that uses OpenIdConnect to authenticate to Azure AD B2C. When a user has authenticated, we would like to be able to acquire accesstokens from Azure AD B2C, in order to use them our API.

This is our Startup.cs-equivalent code:

```
protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));

    List<B2CConfig> ssoSettings = _ssoConfigurationRepository.GetAllSettings();

    foreach (var config in ssoSettings)
    {
        args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromSiteConfig(config));
    }
}

private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromSiteConfig(B2CConfig config)
{
    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions();
    options.MetadataAddress = string.Format(_aadInstance, _tenant, config.Policy);
    options.AuthenticationType = config.Policy;
    options.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive;
    options.RedirectUri = config.AzureReplyUri;
    options.PostLogoutRedirectUri = config.LogoutRedirectUri;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "emails"
    };

    var identityProvider = GetIdentityProvider();

    options.Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
        {
            return Task.FromResult(notification.ProtocolMessage.UiLocales = config.UiLocale ?? string.Empty);
        },
        SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
        {
            notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("idp", "azureadb2c"));

            // transform all claims
            ClaimsIdentity identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
            notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.ApplyClaimsTransformations(new TransformationContext(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };

    options.ClientId = config.ClientId;
    options.Scope = "openid";
    options.ResponseType = "id_token";

    return options;
}

private Task AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
    notification.HandleResponse();

    // Handle the error code that Azure AD B2C throws when trying to reset a password from the login page
    // because password reset is not supported by a "sign-up or sign-in policy"
    if (notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription != null && notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
    {
        SsoLogger.Warn("User triggered reset password");
        notification.Response.Redirect(SsoConfiguration.Routes.ResetPassword);
    }
    else if (notification.Exception.Message == "access_denied")
    {
        notification.Response.Redirect("/");
    }
    else
    {
        SsoLogger.Warn("AuthenticationFailed", notification.Exception);
        notification.Response.Redirect(SsoConfiguration.Routes.LoginError);
    }

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

In Asp.Net core it seems like you would call `GetTokenAsync` on the HttpContext, but that extensionmethod is not available in .NET 4.72.

Can anyone help figuring out, how to retrieve an accesstoken from AzureAD B2C, that can be used in the calls to our WebApi? Or can I just store the accesstoken I get from the SecurityTokenValidated event and use that for all API requests?

Comment: You can refer to this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs. The related document is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-app?tabs=applications.

Comment: The authentication part works - I just need to know how to acquire accesstokens afterwards

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution: [Is it safe to store an access_token in a user claim for authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510961/is-it-safe-to-store-an-access-token-in-a-user-claim-for-authorization)

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
    SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
    {
        var identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
        identity.AddClaim(claim: new Claim(type: "auth_token", value: 
           notification.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

If anyone has a better approach I will gladly accept another answer.